How to parallelize NUnit tests that need to use FileParameter?

.NET 8.0
NUnit 4.1.0

I have a bunch of tests that are wrapped within a TestFixture attribute.
Each test case is currently opening a file as a FileParameter and passing that to a function:
string path = "./filepath";
FileParameter file = new(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open));
_ = await SomeFunction(file);
file.Data.Close();

I want to parallelize the execution of each test case within the fixture. I have been able to do this with other fixtures using [Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Children)], which runs all tests within the fixture at once.
The problem is that if the test is opening and closing a file then the file will close before the other test has a chance to use it, if they are running simultaneously.
What is the best way to parallelize this, so that each test can open the same file and use it at the same time?
It is not an option to read the file content as a string and use that.

There's no FileParameter in .NET. Are you asking how to use the same file from multiple threads?

My recommendation would be to copy the data to a memory stream:
private byte[] data;

[OneTimeSetUp]
public void OneTimeSetUp()
{
    data = File.ReadAllBytes("./filepath");
}

[Test]
public async void MyTest()
{
    using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(data);
    FileParameter file = new( memoryStream );
    _ = await SomeFunction(file);
}

This ensures that all tests can be run in parallel, and should also help with performance. If tests write to the stream you probably want to create a copy of the data for each test.
This approach will not be suitable if you actually require an actual file stream, or the the file is unfeasible large to keep in memory. But if this is the case you probably want to run such tests sequentially to avoid issues, and possibly put them in a separate category, so they do not slow down all the other tests.

If each test only needs to have read access then you can share the read-only file between each execution by defining the FileAccess and FileShare constants.
string path = "./filepath";
FileParameter file = new(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read));
_ = await SomeFunction(file);
file.Data.Close();


A much better option would be to create a copy of the file for each test instead of having all files use the same file. If you have to modify anything you could easily end up with Access Denied errors or inconsistent data
